# Circular Bend Shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, illustration

I'm going to try to replicate [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/24/wobbly-slideshow-effect/) tutorial on creating a wobbly slide show but instead of a square svg, I am trying to use a circular shape.

The square image is comprised of the below:

[image]

What would a circular image image in motion look like? I'm having troubles imagining this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it slightly different than @Ryan's answer (but not necessarily more accurate :) ).

Since the squares maintain the same vertical height and simply arch left or right, the circles should as well.

Using **illustrator** and applying the same left and right arch (via `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp`) to the outer circles yields this:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well going off your example:

The left most side leads when going left while the right most side drags while going left. So the same should be true for a circular shape, if you want to use the same effect. And of course the opposite for the other direction:

[image]

Can of course extend more or less based on your taste. Have fun with it.